# CSS Keyframe Animations stopped working in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, css-animations

So these animations **were working fine until sometime recently**, they still work in edge but not in Firefox or Chrome.  I have searched for a few hours but no one seems to be having this issue currently.  I have also tried putting the prefixes for -webkit- and -moz- and it still did not work.  Any help would be much appreciated!

```css
@keyframes gradientBG {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 50%;
  }
}

.freeTrialButton a:hover { 
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #4575ff, #2a50bd, #4575ff, #4575ff) !important; 
  background-size: 400% 400% !important; 
  animation: gradientBG 3s ease infinite; 
  opacity: 1 !important; 
  color: #fff !important;
}
```